# とする・にする before a noun

Tags: grammar

> 「**竜の歯を依り代とした人型**はコルキス王の魔術と聞く。
>   その娘、王女メディアは稀代の魔女と謳われたそうだが？」

Does this mean:

> The human form who made the dragon tooth as a vessel

or

> A human form which was a dragon tooth made vessel.

How does にする・とする work before a name?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18593/5010

Comment: I found that, but my question here is if :XをYとするN means:  "N makes X into Y" or if it means "N is X made into Y".

Comment: As you can see in the linked question, XをYとする/したN is simply "N where X is Y" or "N with X as Y". BTW what's 人型? Is that a type of magic in this novel?

Comment: Yes, I read it a long time ago so I don't remember what it was specifically.  It was not that important since it was never mentioned again.

Answer (score 7):

`A を B に／とする` means either *make A into B* or *have A as B*. Whether the change of state is involved or not (i.e. *A* is "made" into *B* or originally so) is unspecified and always left ambiguous, so you can only choose the right side from context.

> 人型 that made a dragon tooth into the (spirit) vessel
> *or*
> 人型 using a dragon tooth as the (spirit) vessel

<sup>(I don't have any idea what 人型 stands for, though...)</sup>

This type of ambiguity is parallel to that of English passive construction.

> *The project is finally completed.* → changes from "WIP" to "done".
> *The project is already completed.* → keeps the "done" state.

If you dig a little deeper, using the particle に or と makes some difference in nuance. According to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910033102/http://www.alc.co.jp/jpn/article/faq/03/85.html), と suggests the result is authentic, finalized, or established, whereas に comparatively ad-hoc, questionable, or figurative.

There are some idioms exclusively allow either of them.

> ○ [身を粉にする](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/edc/5000273001/meaning/m0u/%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%92%E7%B2%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)
> × 身を粉とする