# What is this と? 芸術家は芸術を仕事としている人

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 芸術家は芸術を仕事としている人。
> Concerning an artist, it is a person who does art for a living (=as a job).

I didn't encounter と in this kind of function yet, or at least not often enough to remember it. Did I translate this correctly?

Comment: AをBとする comes up a lot on this site but it's not so easy to search for. Try this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33722/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-before-a-noun

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「Noun A + **を** + Noun B + **と** + する」

means:

> "to regard A as B"
>
> "to let A be B"
>
> "to treat A as B"
>
> "to have A as B", etc.

Thus, your translation is not bad at all.