# 私はこの失敗を出発点としてもう一度初めから頑張るつもりです。

Tags: meaning

I am not sure what this means:

> 私はこの失敗を出発点としてもう一度初めから頑張るつもりです。

Here is my go at it:

> This mistake will be used/made as a starting point, one more time for something or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issues you are having with this line may be similar to those in [this other question of yours here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90762).

I linked [a very helpful answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54632/what-is-this-%E3%81%A8/54637#54637) in my answer there.

> 私はこの失敗を出発点としてもう一度初めから頑張るつもりです。

can be rendered roughly as:

> I intend to take this failure as a new point of departure, start over, and work hard.