# 週三回以上働けることを条件としてアルバイトの人を募集した。

Tags: meaning

I do not understand the meaning of the として here.

This is my go at it:

> 週三回以上働けることを条件としてアルバイトの人を募集した。
> 3 times a week or more, able to work thing, with a procedure, as a procedure, part time worker applied.

how can I make this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This として is explained here in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54637/30454). Taking the sentence apart:

> 週三回以上働けること　　を　　条件　　として
> Noun phrase　　　　particle　　noun　　連用形 of とする

This phrase means "using [being able to work at least days (times) a week] as a condition"

The gist is:

> [They] were looking for part-timers, using being able to work at least days (times) a week as a condition.

Or

> [They] were looking for part-timers who could work at least three days a week.