# Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした

Tags: grammar

While studying I found this grammar form, which I kinda understand by instinct, but can't actually formalize in my head; this is what the book say:

> [~を~であると考えて]
>
> 1) 祖父は今日も孫のヒロシを話し相手**にして**散歩に出かけた。
>
> 2) 今回のキャンプを最後に、わたしたちのグループは解散することになった。
>
> 3) 卒業を1つの区切り**として**、これからは自立して生きていきたい。
>
> 4) この大会に参加できるのは社会奉仕を目的**とする**団体だけです。
>
> 5) この研究会では環境問題を中心**とした**さまざまな問題を話し合いたいと思う。
>
> 「N1をN2にして」という形で、ある行動や場面において、N1はN2であると言いたいときの表現。

I think I kinda get the general meaning:

> 1) 祖父は今日も孫のヒロシを話し相手**にして**散歩に出かけた。
>
> <sub>Today Hiroshi's grandfather went out walking again with is grandchild Hiroshi as speaking partner [something like they speak while they walk, I guess?]</sub>
>
> 2) 今回のキャンプを最後に、わたしたちのグループは解散することになった。
>
> <sub>It was decided that at the end of this camp our group would be dispersed</sub>
>
> 3) 卒業を1つの区切り**として**、これからは自立して生きていきたい。
>
> <sub>As one of the end of graduation, I want to be able to live indipendently from now on</sub>
>
> 4) この大会に参加できるのは社会奉仕を目的とする団体だけです。
>
> <sub>Only associations working in the voluntary social services can attend this assembly</sub>
>
> 5) この研究会では環境問題を中心**とした**さまざまな問題を話し合いたいと思う。
>
> <sub>In this seminar, whose focus are enviromental issues, I wat to discuss many issues</sub>

My problem is, I can't formalize this in my head, and my Japanese is failing me in clearly understanding the book's explanation (`[~を~であると考えて]` and `「N1をN2にして」という形で、ある行動や場面において、N1はN2であると言いたいときの表現`); it seems to mean "N1 is N2", but then again I'm not sure about the sentences:

> 祖父は今日も孫のヒロシを話し相手にとして散歩に出かけた

This seems to be `祖父はN1をN2として`, whith N1 = `孫のヒロシ` and N2 = `話し相手`; so... the grandchild is the speaking partner? And the sentence means something like "As for the grandfather [祖父は], he went out to take a walk [散歩に出かけた] with his grandchild as speaking partner [孫のヒロシを話し相手にとして]"? Is in て-form because after the sentence continues, while `とする` would be used if the sentence ended?

If I were to asnwer to the question "Ok, but what does it mean?" I'd be confused explaining; it's kinds "N1 as N2", "N1 is N2", but I'm not sure that's all there is. The second sentence is proving particulary difficult to fit in this framework:

> 2) 今回のキャンプを最後に、わたしたちのグループは解散することになった。

N1 = `今回のキャンプ`, N2 = `最後(に)`? Or does N2 comprise something more? I can't fit it in "N1 is N2" frame no matter how I parse it.

I also found [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18593/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%82%92-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%82%92-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-before-nouns) question, which kinds seems to confirm my intuition, but it doesn't really help in formalizing it.

Edit: the book explains all the forms in the title with the same examples and explanation, hence this question's title; not sure about any difference among those forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the time, you can think of the "AをBに(して)" construction as "with A as B", "with A at/in B", or "thinking/making/using A as B". This has been asked many times, so please take a look at [these questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20854?lq=1) linked to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/5010). AをBにする and AをBとする are usually interchangeable, but for the subtle difference, see [とする・にする before a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33722/5010)

- 孫のヒロシを話し相手に
  = 孫のヒロシを話し相手にして
  = 孫のヒロシを話し相手として
  with his grandson Hiroshi as his chat partner (にとして must be a typo.)
- 卒業を1つの区切りに
  = 卒業を1つの区切りにして
  = 卒業を1つの区切りとして
  with/making this graduation as a turning point (of my life)
- 今日のキャンプを最後に
  = 今日のキャンプを最後にして
  = 今日のキャンプを最後として
  with/thinking/making this camp as the last one

These are adverbial (i.e., verb-modifying) expressions, but "AをB{と/に}{した/する}" forms attributive (i.e., noun-modifying) expressions as relative clauses.

- 社会奉仕を目的に(して)
  with social services as the purpose
  → for the purpose of social services
- 社会奉仕を目的{にする/にした/とする/とした}団体
  organizations for social services
- 環境問題を中心に(して)
  with environmental problems as the core
  → focusing on environmental problems
- 環境問題を中心{にする/にした/とする/とした}さまざまな問題
  various issues around environmental problems

Comment: Can you possibly help me understand the first and last sentences of the quote? My obviously wrong understanding is... [~を~であると考えて]. This looks like beginning of an exercise, "think about the ~を~である pattern." 「N1をN2にして」という形で、(not sure what で here means, maybe "with the form called N1をN2にして")ある行動や場面において、("putting [something] at a place and behavior that exist)N1はN2であると言いたいときの表現("[something] is a time expression that one want to call N1はN2である")。In other words I can't make sense of it.