# The meaning (and reading) of 間 in context of people, 境 and 混, does it mean 'getting into a group or clique'?

Tags: grammar, meaning, readings, literature

I'm slowly, very very slowly working through [this story here](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n9105fz/1/) while I study kanji (using kanjidamage) and with basic Japanese grammar skills, very much a beginner.

間 seems to be leaning toward '[period of time](https://www.kanjidamage.com/kanji/162-a-period-of-time-%E9%96%93)'

However, this section suggest more like "intruding into a group" or something, like ones little brother trying to slowly make himself a part of you and your friends group of makebelieve super sentai band.

> ある日を**境に俺とヴィンスの間に混ざるようになったエミーは**、木の枝を見つけてきては、勝ち気な青い目を長い金髪の間に覗かせながら、俺たちの間に入ってきた。

Is that true? Or is it still more like a period of time? Like a process or something? 
Also, how is it read? "Ma"? A furigana addon I downloaded puts "ma" over the 間, as does Google translate.

Comment: This 境に is part of ある日を境に, which is [AをBに construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73094/5010). Literally, "with one day as a turning point", or simply, "after one certain day".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ある日を**境に俺とヴィンスの間に混ざるようになったエミーは**、木の枝を見つけてきては、勝ち気な青い目を長い金髪の間に覗かせながら、俺たちの間に入ってきた。

It is read as 「あいだ」.  In the first (俺とヴィンスの間に) and third (俺たちの間に) usages of this sentence, it means "among" or "within".  It *could* mean "between" as far as a spatial distance, but without context from previous sentences, I'd say it's unlikely.

In the second usage (長い金髪の間に), it means like "between" or even "through".  But that's the beauty of Japanese; you don't have to know which exact definition it is to understand the overall meaning!

See definitions 1 and 5 [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%96%93).