# What's the difference between としたところで and　にしたところで and how to use it in a "positive" way

Tags: grammar, jlpt

「A に/としたところで　B」 is really confusing me.

According to my textbook the difference seems to be that にしたところで is used with nouns while everything else takes としたところで。

According to this [website](https://chiyo-sampo.net/grammar-jlptn1-nishitatokorode/), however, there is no such restriction but they do state that there is a small difference in meaning which unfortunately they do not explain.
The found an answer on another [website](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/5130786) where the explanation went along the lines

> にしたところで　= even if A is the case, you shouldn't do be/B is not possible
> としたところで　₌ however much you do A, B is not possible<

That sounds like a pretty big difference my book/websites should mention. Is it then correct?

Also on the first website mentioned above they state that there are exceptions where B doesn't express some kind of incompetence or meaninglessness. One sentence I think fits the description would be

> 「一つの言葉にしたって、聞く側によって意味は変わる。」<

Which I would translate with
"Depending on who is listening even a single word can change the meaning".
But if the translation is more or less correct, it would be quite different from the meaning above, wouldn't it?

Comment: Re: "it would be quite different from the meaning above, wouldn't it?", I think usage is actually quite similar, at least on a semantic level: *even if A, you can't assume B* → *even if it's (just) a single word, you can't assume it won't (greatly) affect how the whole (story/context) is interpreted*. +1 regarding your main question though.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to answer, but I think the difference lies in the difference between にしたら and としたら. としたら is more hypothetical than にしたら. So にしたところで is used for a current or highly plausible situation, whereas としたところで would be used for a more hypothetical situation 'even if we were to' sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, native Japanese speakers hardly ever say "～に/としたところで", and often use "～にしても/～としても" alternatively, because the later conjunctions are shorter and more casual than the former.

Then let's think about "～にしても/～としても".

> ex. 一つの言葉にしたって,聞く人によって意味は変わる。
> *Depending on who is listening even a single word can change the meaning.*

In this sentence, we can substitute ～にしても for ～にしたって, but cannot do ～としても.

If you wanna use としても, you should modify"～だとしても"

Well then, see the usage of ～に/としたところで.

Compared with ～にしても/～としても, "～に/としたところで" differs a little in a relationship between the preceding and following sentences. When you write or read sentences which contains に/としたところで, the logical relationship between clauses would be important.

In order to better understanding ～に/としたところで, let's disassemble に/としたところで into にする/とする and ところで.

noun. /adj. + にする/とする : put into a certain state.
*ex. 部屋を綺麗にする/make room clean*

> Clarkをリーダーとする空の民(Skaikru)/ Skaikru with Clark as a leader

verb. + (～しよう)とする : try to do.
*ex. 寝ようとする/try to sleep*

ところで : one of conjectives,it means paradox【逆説】 or converse【転換】.

【転換】: By the way.

> ex.今日は晴れですね。ところで、昨日のテストはどうでしたか？

【逆説】: The later section shows that the result is the opposite of what is expected from the previous section.

However,"ところで" alone doesn't make sense of【逆説】,we need to use in combine with "～する".

Thus, ～に/としたところで leads a paradoxical(逆説的な) sentence.

There is no unique translation,but I seem "No matter what" and "Even if" are suitable.

> ex. ジュースを買おうとしたところで、財布を持っていないことに気づいた。
> *When I attempted to buy juice, I realized that I didn't have a wallet.*

> ex. 目隠しをしたところで、彼はすぐにルービックキューブを解けます。
> *Even if he blindfold himself, he can solve Rubik's Cube immediately.*

To be blindfolded is a handicap or adversity to solving the cube, but he is so ingenious that he can solve it in that situation.

Like this when A has negative nuances, it can lead to a positive sentence.

By the way(ところで【転換】), the difference among ～に/と/を +したところで is something like case inflection or postpositional particles. There is no difference in meaning, but 目隠しとする or 目隠しにする seem a little strange.

For details, see [this following bulletin board](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73094).

Answer (score -2):

> What's the difference between としたところで and　にしたところで

に：essential elements,inner power

と：target, far away

Guys, before downvoting, please look up these two partiles from 岩波古語辞典 . It's really difficult to describe them in human language. I am just expressing my feelings on these two particles.