# ある機会を好機と捉えて - を～と～verb, how to understand this?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

The word I searched up is "ここぞとばかりに"

> ある機会を好機と捉えてさかんに働きかけるさまなどを意味する表現

an expression of taking a chance as a good opportunity to eagerly pressure

Is this related to [Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73082/45598)?