# この会は会長の木村さんを中心にいろいろな活動をしている。

Tags: meaning

I need to confirm my meaning of the following sentence:

> この会は会長の木村さんを中心にいろいろな活動をしている。

My go:

> If Kimura-san was here in this meeting, then it will be exciting.

Can someone explain what this means?

Comment: There are two を's in this sentence. Just so we are clear, when you say を as a question marker, are you talking about 「木村さん**を**中心に」 or 「いろいろな活動**を**している」?

Comment: @EddieKal Hello Eddie Van Halen, First can you please explain what is a question marker?  I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: こっちのセリフだけど。 Well, you mentioned "question marker" in your original post...

Comment: @EddieKal  Ok I took it out, so now can you answer what it means?

Comment: Study [を中心に](https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/23616029.html) first.

Comment: @JimmyYang Well according to your link, it says concentration, that does not help one bit at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this 会 means *club*, *group* or *society* rather than an individual *meeting*. Second, there is no word for *if* in your sentence. Third, いろいろな活動 is *various activities*, and there is no word for *exciting* in your sentence. Fourth, you have [already asked about this Aを中心に construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90744/5010) (or more broadly `AをBに`) several times. `AをBに` is a very important pattern and you can read dozens of questions about it [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20854?lq=1). 会長の木村さんを中心に is adverbially modifying 活動をしている.

Without this part, the sentence should be easy:

> この会はいろいろな活動をしている。
>
> This group is working on various activities.

And with the Aを中心に part:

> この会は**会長の木村さんを中心に**いろいろな活動をしている。
>
> (literally) This group, **with the chairman Mr. Kimura at its center,** is working on various activities.
>
> This group, led by the chairman Mr. Kimura, is working on various activities.