# 数人の学生を取り巻きに歩くその後ろ姿へ向けて、いのは叫んだ

Tags: meaning

> 数人の学生を取り巻きに歩くその後ろ姿へ向けて、いのは叫んだ。

The translation should be something along the lines of "Ino shouted at the figure who was walking with a few students around them".
In my mind though this sentence is translated into "Ino shouted at the figure who was walking while surrounding a few students".
Can anyone help me break down this phrase?

Comment: I've been reviewing this sentence for a while and might've find the solution. A "missing" して because of a double accusative?

Comment: Possibly the following resolves your doubts https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73082/45489