# this sentence seem lacking verb to me?how can i understand it properly pls help me translate it

Tags: particle-を

> 日本語は地方ごとに多様な方言があり、とりわけ琉球諸島で方言差が著しい（「方言」の節参照）。近世中期までは京都方言が中央語の地位にあったが、近世後期には江戸方言が地位を高め、明治以降の現代日本語では東京山の手の中流階級以上の方言（山の手言葉）**を**基盤に標準語（共通語）が形成された.

I assume 東京山の手の中流階級以上の方言（山の手言葉）を基盤に標準語（共通語）が形成された mean: (the diaclect of yamanote above middle class ) is basically founded  ...standard language(wide used language) is created

Why does the phrase 東京山の手の中流階級以上の方言（山の手言葉）を基盤に seem lacking the verb and suddenly jump into another phrase, pls enlighten me (is it because of the particle wo?)

Also,

> 音韻は「子音＋母音」音節を基本とし、母音は5種類しかないなど、分かりやすい構造を持つ一方、直音と拗音の対立、「1音節2モーラ」の存在、無声化母音、語の組み立てに伴って移動する高さアクセントなどの特徴がある（「音韻」の節参照）

what does 無声化母音 mean?

Comment: It can be understood as "を基盤にして". See the answer here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/meaning-of-%e3%82%92%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%82%92%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%82%92%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e3%82%92%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e3%82%92%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-%e3%82%92%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f As for the 無音化母音, isn't it just "devoiced vowel(s)"?

Comment: thank you very much ʚ♡ɞ